# How to best write Next router.query in Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am new to Typescript and still figuring out how to use it. I have a function that takes as first parameter Next's useRouter query object and as second parameter a string (literal type 'a', 'b' or 'c').

The function checks if the given parameter is present on the query object and if it's value is not empty (!== ''). It returns an empty array if these conditions where not met and an array of the values if these conditions were met. (for example url?a=foo,bar would return ['foo', 'bar'].

Here is the function:

```
/**
 * validate query parameter: the @param is in @query and it's value is not empty
 * @param query - useRouter query
 * @param parameter - a, b or c
 * @returns empty array or array of strings
 */

function validateQueryParameter(
  query: ParsedUrlQuery,
  parameter: 'a' | 'b' | 'c',
): string[] {
  if (!query.hasOwnProperty(parameter)) return []
  if (query[parameter] === '') return []
  const queryString = query[parameter] as string
  return queryString.split(',')
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function SomeComponent(){
  const router = useRouter()
  const validatedQuery = validateQueryParameter(router.query, 'a')
  return 'hello world'
}
```

My question is: can this be written better and if so, how? For example using the nullish coallescing operator or optional chaining?